# Remove body from world when a collision occurs

Tags: java, android, box2d, libgdx

I'm super new to libgdx and java.

I'm extending the [Simple App](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/SimpleApp) game from libgdx's documentation.
I made the raindrops and the bucket bodies, and also made a "ground" body.

The tutorial handles collision detection this way:

```
Iterator < Body > iter = raindrops.iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    Body raindrop = iter.next();
    if (raindrop.y + 64 < 0) {
        dropped++;
        iter.remove();
    }
    if (raindrop.overlaps(bucket)) {
        dropSound.play();
        catched++;
        iter.remove();
    }
}
```

And it worked as intended, but since I made every raindrop a body, I can't use the `overlaps()` function any more, so I had to use box2d's collision detection:

```
Iterator < Body > iter = raindrops.iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    Body raindrop = iter.next();

    world.setContactListener(new ContactListener() {

        @Override
        public void beginContact(Contact contact) {
            Fixture fixtureA = contact.getFixtureA();
            Fixture fixtureB = contact.getFixtureB();
            if ((String) fixtureA.getBody().getUserData() == "bucket" && (String) fixtureB.getBody().getUserData() == "drop" || (String) fixtureA.getBody().getUserData() == "drop" && (String) fixtureB.getBody().getUserData() == "bucket") {
                //csepp és vödör ütközik
                dropSound.play();
                catched++;
                iter.remove();

            }
            if ((String) fixtureA.getBody().getUserData() == "ground" && (String) fixtureB.getBody().getUserData() == "drop" || (String) fixtureA.getBody().getUserData() == "drop" && (String) fixtureB.getBody().getUserData() == "ground") {
                //csepp és föld ütközik
                dropped++;
                iter.remove();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void endContact(Contact contact) {}

        @Override
        public void preSolve(Contact contact, Manifold oldManifold) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void postSolve(Contact contact, ContactImpulse impulse) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    });
}
```

My main problem is, that `iter.remove();` doesn't remove the correct raindrop. Upon collision it removes the newest raindrop, not the one that collided with the bucket.

Also, the box2d body doesn't get removed.

How can I do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't save Strings as the UserData, save a reference to your entities instead (raindrop, bucket...). Then you will know which Raindrop exactly caused the collision and you can remove exactly that one. The Body will be removed via `World.destroyBody(...)`.

BUT you cannot call that method while the physics step is in processing. That means, you cannot use it directly in your collision callbacks.

Instead: Put the bodies to be removed in a temporary list and run through this list after the physics step and remove them.

Comment: What do you mean by "save a reference to your entities"? Can you show me an example please? Thanks!

Comment: @Tharline uuum standard java references... for example when you create the body in your Raindrop constructor: body.setUserData(this). The userdata can be any random object. That means it can be ANYTHING and is not limited to Strings.

Comment: example of saving reference is given in one of the answers

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17829115/libgdx-and-box2d-detect-collision-of-two-specific-bodies/17829707#17829707

check it out