# libgdx - collision with an object made by different bodies

Tags: libgdx, listener, box2d, collision-detection

Hi I have an object which is composed by several bodies, the differences between them is that someone is a filter and someone else is not.
I want my actor to be destroyed when colliding with the physic side and to have a different effect when colliding with the sensor one.
So how can I check in my collision listener if the contact is happening in one part or in another?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17829115/libgdx-and-box2d-detect-collision-of-two-specific-bodies/17829707#17829707

this might help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you have a table and a bunch of cows, you want to determine if any cow collided with the table.

```
Body table;
Array<Body> cows;

//define the table and cows

ContactListener listener = new ContactListener() {

  @Override
  public void beginContact(Contact contact) {
    Body bodyA = contact.getFixtureA().getBody();
    Body bodyB = contact.getFixtureB().getBody();

    for (Body cow : cows) {
      if (((cow == bodyA) || (cow == bodyB)) &&
         ((table == bodyA) || (table == bodyB))) {
          //do something
      }
    }
  }
};
```

It's a generic answer, but It tells you how to check which bodies have collided which I believe answers your question.

Comment: My contact listener has no visibility on my objects. The project is a game with several levels and I create new instance of different kind of objects in any level. Can I check which body (from the bodies that are attributes of the colliding Class) is colliding with the other actor just by these bodyA and bodyB? My technique by now was something like "if (bodyA.getUserata() instaceof ClassA && bodyB.getUserData() instance of ClassB)" but in this case being instance of the class is not enough, I need to now if it is a specific body of that class

Comment: As long as you provide a getter method in the objects of your class that can be accessed by the listener that could tell the listener if the body is collideable. Something like `bodyA.isCollideable();` You would cast the Body to your body class. `MyBodyClass bodyA = (MyBodyClass) contact.getFictureA().getBody();` An alternative to extending Body and adding a getter method would be to use `get[set]UserData()` to set and get a `boolean` if the body is collideable.

Comment: My Class doesn't extend Body. It has three bodies like attributes and just one of them should be crossable with other side effects to implement in the listener

Comment: What about setting user data to a boolean telling if the body is collideable?

Comment: as simple as `body.setUserData(true)` or `body.setUserData(false)` then `bodyA.getUserData()` will return true or false. cast the getter to boolean and you should be good to go

Comment: It works fine, thank you! I think I needed some further documentation about userdata...

Answer (score 0):

There are probably many ways to do this, but here is how I do my physics to game object mapping. Not something I stick to religiously, but I try to - there are always exceptions.

If I have a "game object", it has one body. The bodies user data is set to that object.

If I have a "game object" that is made up of parts, these parts are "game object parts", and they will be the userdata of the Fixtures of the body.

My "Game Object" is a composite of the "Part Objects" in the same way as a Body has Fixture parts.

If you have something like this, then you can distinguish between the parts of your object in collisions easily I think. If you truly want your "Game Object" to be made up of multiple bodies for some other reason, then I would still make the "Game Object" have "Parts" that are set to the user data of the bodies that make it up. Hope that helps.

I also take it another step further - my "game objects" have their own collection of collision handlers. So my single registered collision listener gets the userdata objects and calls their collision handlers with the same parameters. Leverage the polymorphism dude. Now I can attach the collision behaviour I want for a given object to that object. I don't have to loop through all my objects to decide what to do in my registered collision listener.

Comment: I already solved my case, the collision handler part was a good idea and very useful though